# Powershell Try/catch - get-user

Tags: windows, powershell, try-catch, exchange-server, powershell-ise

I'm learning `posh`. And I'm trying to understand why this script doesn't catch the warning.

```
try{
    get-user aaaa -WarningAction Stop
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "hi"
}
```

Here is the error:

```
get-user : The operation couldn't be performed because object 'aaaa' couldn't be found on
'iDC01.contoso.com'. At C:\Users\Gra***\Desktop\test.ps1:2 char:5
+     get-user aaaa -WarningAction Stop
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-User], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=ME1,RequestId=ebcde0d2-9222-443b-b25a-ef7279fd168e,
      TimeStamp=20.06.2017 13:51:35] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ManagementObjectNotFoundException]
      FE0D594D,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.GetUser
```

I've tryied `-WarningActions Stop` and `-ErrorAction Stop` but no results.

In general I've understood the basics of `try/catch` and the following script works ok.

```
try{
Get-Process -name xyz -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch{
Write-Host "oops"
}
```

I'm using `powershell_ise 5.1`. Do you know what's wrong with the `get-user`? 
Also, I can't use `Get-ADuser`.

Comment: `get-user` is not a native PowerShell command. What does the code for this function look like?

Comment: `Get-User` is documented as being an Exchange cmdlet, and will only return objects from Exchange.

Comment: You set the WarningAction, but not the ErrorAction. Your ErrorActionPreference was probably Continue when you ran this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that can be caught when calling a function, Error or Warning.  You can set these with the `$WarningPreference` or `$ErrorActionPreference` globally in the script, or individually by using the -ea or -wa arguments.  In your example, I'd use the following to be sure:

```
Try {
    Get-User aaaa -wa Stop -ea Stop
} Catch {
    Write-Output "hi"
    Write "[$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)] - $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

[about_Preference_Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables)

Comment: Thank you @TheIncorrigible1 and Paal Braathen. But I tried -ErrorAction Stop and it didn't help. And I found out that this happens because I use Remote-powershell via New-PSSession. It works ok on the server.

Answer (score -1):

Late to the party, but this worked for me

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
try {
    $test = (query user /server:$PCname | findstr -i -v 
    'sessionname')
}catch{#blah }
```

You might also try putting "write-output $_" at the end of your try scriptblock to see what the error looks like if it's giving you trouble.

Comment: It is best practice to stay within PowerShell if possible to keep being able to use the benefits of structured objects and error handling.